# UnsatisfiedLinkError with JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

.h file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "NativePackage_HelloWorld.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativePackage_HelloWorld_displayHelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)   {
printf("Hello world!\n");
return;
}
```

Java

```
package NativePackage;

public class HelloWorld {
public native void displayHelloWorld();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().displayHelloWorld();
}
}
```

.c file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "NativePackage_HelloWorld.h" 
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativePackage_HelloWorld_displayHelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
printf("Hello world!\n");
return;
}
```

I've compiled my .c file using

```
gcc -I /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/ -I  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/ -fPIC -o hello -c   HelloWorldImp.c
```

However, trying to run using `java NativePackage/HelloWorld` produce the following error:

```
java  -Djava.library.path=NativePackage/ NativePackage/HelloWorld

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hello in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at NativePackage.HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

I'm running on a MAC OS X 10.10

Comment: It should be `java  -Djava.library.path=NativePackage/ NativePackage.HelloWorld`. Where did you put the 'hello' shared library?

Comment: in NativePackage/, Also I'm not sure about the naming for the shared library should it be only hello or libhello.so

Comment: Try compiling with the `-shared` flag, and the naming scheme of libraries on Mac OS X is `libXXX.dylib`

Comment: Thanks Samuel, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like things worked with using the correct naming scheme for OS X *libhello.dylib* and the *-shared* option.

```
gcc -I /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/ -I /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/  -o libhello.dylib -shared HelloWorldImp.c
```

Comment: .dylib instead of .so in Mac

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
System.load("/home/project/lib/libhello.so");
```

give the absolute path for the library.

that helped me when i had the same problem.

Comment: This worked well, however the naming was incorrect for OS X, this is true for linux. Also, I had a compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

For an updated answer for macOS Monterey 12.6.1

## HelloWorld.c

```c
#include <jni.h>        // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <stdio.h>      // C Standard IO Header
#include "HelloWorld.h"   // Generated
 
// Implementation of the native method sayHello()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_someNativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

## HelloWorld.java

```java
class HelloWorld {
    private native void someNativeMethod();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().someNativeMethod();
    }
    static {
        // must be word between lib and .dylib, e.g. libMyNative.dylib
        System.loadLibrary("MyNative");
    }
}
```

## Run

```
# compile java - generates HelloWorld.h and HelloWorld.class
javac -h . HelloWorld.java

# compile native c files
gcc -I "$JAVA_HOME/include" -I "$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin" -dynamiclib -o libMyNative.dylib -shared HelloWorld.c

# run all
java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
```

---

Tested on macOS Monterey 12.6.1

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```